# PHP's similar_text() and in_array() not working as it seems like they should

Tags: php

I am trying to use `similar_text()` and `in_array()` to make a simple spellcheck and suggestions program in PHP.
I have a text file, dictionary.txt, that is most of the words in the english language.

First, I put all the words in the text file each on a new line into an array. Then on user input and submission, I check if the word they entered is in the array using `in_array()`. If it is, then they spelled it correctly.

If it is not, then I use `similar_text()` to find words in the array that are close to the misspelled word.

I am encountering two problems that I haven't been able to solve and I believe I am using `in_array()` and `similar_text()` properly according to the PHP documentation.

First problem is that when the user types and submits words that are in the text file and should also be in the array, the else fires and that shouldn't happen. Since it is in the text file, it should be in the array, and `in_array()` should evaluate to true.

Second problem is that I am getting an error that the variable where I am storing the percentage of similarity between the two words via `similar_text()` is not defined.
I am using it, `similar_text()`, just like in the documentation comments examples;in fact, I am resetting and redefining `$percentageSimilarity` before each comparison. Why am I getting the error that it is not defined?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function addTo($line){
    return $line;
}
$words = array_map('addTo', file('dictionary.txt'));
if(isset($_GET['checkSpelling'])){
    $input = (string)$_GET['checkSpelling'];
    $suggestions = array();
    if(in_array($input, $words)){
        echo "you spelled the word right!";
    }
    else{
        foreach($words as $word){
            $percentageSimilarity=0.0;
            similar_text($input, $word, $percentageSimilarity);
            if($percentageSimilarity>=95){
                 array_push($suggestions, $word);
            }
         }
         echo "Looks like you spelled that wrong. Here are some suggestions: \n";
         foreach($suggestions as $suggestion){
             echo $suggestion;
         }
     }
  }
  ?>
  <!Doctype HTMl>
 <html lang="en">
     <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <title>Spell Check</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <form method="get">
             <input type="text" name="checkSpelling" autocomplete="off" autofocus />
         </form>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: don't know if this is the issue or not but you should be forcing the word all upper or lower and ensure that your word list gets the same treatment. also you should remove all punctuation and non-word characters from both lists as well.

Comment: You're not adding the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag to `file()`.

Comment: @Orangepill I manually removed all punctuation from dictionary.txt. Why would I force all upper? None of the words in dictionary.txt are all upper case. Some, maybe 15% are all lower case.

Comment: @DjangoJohnson You should force all upper or all lower if you what to get a case insensitive match. For example in_array will give you false for "The" if you have "the" in the dictionary. Forcing both the dictionary and the input to all the same case makes this issue go away.

Comment: @Orangepill That is a good point, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your add to line to

```
function addTo($line){
    return strtolower(trim($line));
}
```

and change you input to

```
$input = strtolower(trim($_GET['checkSpelling']));
```

The file command has a nasty habit of leaving the trailing newline character so you probably aren't matching based on that ... the trim should take care of that. The other changes are just there to make it case insensitive.

Comment: This is so very true, it was indeed the newline character

Comment: Thank you, I would have never caught that. Can you help me with one more thing. It is adding the same suggestion mutliple time to the `$suggestions` array. I tried preventing it from doing that by checking if the suggestion was in the array and only adding it if it is not, but that doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code I added: `if($percentageSimilarity>=90){ if(!in_array($suggestions)){ array_push($suggestions, $word); } }` Why is it adding the same suggestion multiple times?

Comment: The only reason I can see how that could happen is if you have the same word in the dictionary multiple times. To scrub out duplicates you can use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `file()`, each element of `$words` will still have the newline character appended to it. You can remove it by using `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`:

```
$words = file('dictionary.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

You could also normalize the needle by applying `strtolower()`, assuming all your dictionary items are already lowercase:

```
if (!($input = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'checkSpelling', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW))) {
    die("Bad input, probably");
}
$input = strtolower($input);
```

This is because `in_array()` doesn't match in a case insensitive manner; e.g. `"Hello" != "hello"`.

Further normalization could include removing anything non-wordy from your words.